# node.js simple proxy server

Tags: javascript, node.js

i'm trying to implement simple anonymous http proxy server in nodejs

```
var http = require('http'),
    request = require('request');
http.createServer(function(req,res){
    req.pipe(request(req.url)).pipe(res)
}).listen(8888)
```

i'm recieving the following error:

```
stream.js:94
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
            ^
Error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
    at SecurePair.<anonymous> (tls.js:1370:32)
    at SecurePair.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at SecurePair.maybeInitFinished (tls.js:982:10)
    at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:469:13)
    at CleartextStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:320:10)
    at EncryptedStream.write [as _write] (tls.js:366:25)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:226:10)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:216:5)
    at EncryptedStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:183:11)
    at write (_stream_readable.js:583:24)
    at flow (_stream_readable.js:592:7)
    at Socket.pipeOnReadable (_stream_readable.js:624:5)
```

Here is another error:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: Invalid protocol
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

`req.url` is a relative path, not a full url. It means that you should add protocol and domain name to it:

```
req.pipe(request('http://mydomain.com'+req.url)).pipe(res)
```

You're also forgetting about `req.method` and `req.headers`:

```
req.pipe(request({
  url: 'http://mydomain.com'+req.url,
  method: req.method,
  headers: req.headers
})).pipe(res)
```

If your purpose is to use it as a real proxy server, then I would recommend you to look at [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) - it's a perfect node.js proxy server implementation.

If you just want to learn node.js, then look at [this article with example proxy server implementation](http://www.catonmat.net/http-proxy-in-nodejs/). Author of the article is using build-in `http` module to send request instead of more powerful [`request` module](https://github.com/mikeal/request) and not using piping, but the rest of the article looks fine.

As for you first problem, [Piotr Tomasik's answer should help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22892201/node-js-simple-proxy-server#22892339).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the domain you are hitting has an expired cert.

Add this to the top of your file.

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';
```

As for your second error, make sure that the url includes the protocol. `http` `https`